# Add tabs to show data that user can't change when signing in Docusign API by uploading pdf using api?

Tags: docusignapi

What code should i add in this in order to show a static text on document(like Amount charged, client name, company name etc) at some place that the user can't change at the time of signing the document and it should show up in the downloaded signed document from Docusign, i am using the request signature on document api walkthrough in this.
Thanks in advance.

```
string xmlBody =
                "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
                "<emailSubject>DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document</emailSubject>" +
                "<status>sent</status>" +   // "sent" to send immediately, "created" to save as draft in your account
                // add document(s)
                "<documents>" +
                "<document>" +
                "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
                "<name>" + documentName + "</name>" +
                "</document>" +
                "</documents>" +
                // add recipient(s)
                "<recipients>" +
                "<signers>" +
                "<signer>" +
                "<recipientId>1</recipientId>" +
                "<email>" + recipientMail + "</email>" +
                "<name>" + recipientName + "</name>" +
                "<tabs>" +
                //myTestCodeStart
                "<tab>" +
                "<DocumentID>1</DocumentID>" +
                "<RecipientID>1</RecipientID>" +
                "<PageNumber>1</PageNumber>" +
                "<XPosition>100</XPosition>" +
                "<YPosition>100</YPosition>" +
                "<ScaleValue>1</ScaleValue>" +
                "<Type>Custom</Type>" +
                "<Name>TestName</Name>" +
                "<TabLabel>LabelTest</TabLabel>" +
                "<Value>TestValue</Value>" +
                "<CustomTabType>Text</CustomTabType>" +
                "<CustomTabWidth>42</CustomTabWidth>" +
                "<CustomTabHeight>11</CustomTabHeight>" +
                "<CustomTabRequired>true</CustomTabRequired>" +
                "<CustomTabLocked>true</CustomTabLocked>" +
                "<CustomTabDisableAutoSize>false</CustomTabDisableAutoSize>" +
                "<CustomTabValidationPattern/>" +
                "<CustomTabValidationMessage/>" +
                "<RequireInitialOnSharedTabChange>false</RequireInitialOnSharedTabChange>" +
                "<ConcealValueOnDocument>false</ConcealValueOnDocument>" +
                "<Bold>false</Bold>" +
                "<Italic>false</Italic>" +
                "<Underline>false</Underline>" +
                "</tab>" +
                //myTestCodeEnd
                "<signHereTabs>" +
                "<signHere>" +
                "<xPosition>350</xPosition>" + // default unit is pixels
                "<yPosition>517</yPosition>" + // default unit is pixels
                "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
                "<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>" +
                "</signHere>" +
                "</signHereTabs>" +
                "</tabs>" +
                "</signer>" +
                "</signers>" +
                "</recipients>" +
                "</envelopeDefinition>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a tab value read-only in the Envelope, set the **locked** property to **true** for that tab.

```
<locked>true</locked>
```

For example, including this XML within a "Create Envelope" request would place the read-only text **123456** within the document (at the specified X/Y location):

```
<textTabs>
   <textTab> 
     <tabLabel>AcctNumber</tabLabel>
     <locked>false</locked>   
     <name>Account Number</name> 
     <value>123456</value>
     <xPosition>100</xPosition>
     <yPosition>200</yPosition>
     <font>arial</font>
     <fontSize>12</fontSize>
     <documentId>1</documentId>
     <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
   </textTab>
</textTabs>
```

(Your code shows you using **<tab>** -- which isn't a valid element name in the REST API. Seems like you should be using <textTabs> and <textTab> as I show in the exxample above.)

Comment: Not working its only showing the signature tab same as before.Tried this.

Comment: Try adding documentId and pageNumber to the XML for the textTab (as I show now in my updated answer).  If that doesn't help, then instead of posting your code that's assembling the XML, please update your question to post the trace of the full XML request that's being sent to the server. You can easily produce a trace of the XML request using Fiddler or something similar. Seeing the actual XML request body (instead of just your code) will provide the information that is necessary for true troubleshooting of this issue.

Comment: Thanks . When i request signature via sending the document it doesn't work and tells me bad data in response. When i use that in a template it works :).